# How do I delete a board from a Trello account?

Tags: trello

I wish to permanently "delete" a board from my account.

There is one entry in the forum asking this question already, but the reply states that you should "close" the board. I am looking for the answer to the question if a board can be permanently removed from the account?

I've just started to play around with Trello and created several boards that are not relevant any more, will never be relevant and I never want to see them again. So, is it possible to "delete" a board? I cannot find a way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

1. Close the board - as you've noted, this is not a permanent deletion
2. See [this card](https://trello.com/card/board-delete/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1313) on the Trello development board to vote for the feature and for a link to a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will submit the "delete board" request as a feature to be added in the future. In the meantime, I can rename one of the existing boards and close the ones I do not need and re-open them in the future if I ever need a new board.

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround that I'm using. If you want to get rid of a board, even if you're the admin, you can follow these steps:

1. Remove any people from the board (It's annoying for other people having a dead board)
2. If you have any sensitive information. Delete the cards
3. So you're the admin, you cannot leave the board, just close it. But..
4. Add Trello user as a new member, and give him admin permission.
5. Now you can leave and get rid the board