# How Could I delete a Closed Board or Unwanted list

Tags: trello

How to delete a closed board

Because it is annoying to show up in my account, i was test the feature, i cannot delete the board and any list, those test and not relate stuff maintain in my account

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to delete a board or list, you are only able to archive them.

There is a card on the Trello Development board for those features. Here is the one for deleting lists https://trello.com/card/delete-lists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1314 and here is the one for deleting boards https://trello.com/card/delete-boards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1313.

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround that I'm using. If you want to get rid of a board, even if you're the admin, you can follow these steps:

1. Remove any people from the board (It's annoying for other people having a dead board)
2. If you have any sensitive information. Delete the cards
3. So you're the admin, you cannot leave the board, just close it. But..
4. Add Trello user as a new member, and give him admin permission.
5. Now you can leave and get rid the board

Answer (score 0):

This question pops up regularly, and is a duplicate of the earlier [How do I delete a board in Trello?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19672/how-do-i-delete-a-board-in-trello) and [How do I delete a board from a Trello account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-do-i-delete-a-board-from-a-trello-account).

Anyway, the trick that I'm using -- it doesn't directly solve your problem, but it is a workaround in some cases -- is that I check the list of closed boards before I create a new one. I rename the board and change the description, and close/rename the unwanted lists.

OK, some of that history (archived lists, cards) will remain in the board history, and only works for your own (personal) boards. You need to balance these drawbacks against having a closed board.

BTW, a closed board never really gets in your way -- you need to explicitly view your list of closed boards to see them. My other trick is that I consider it not my but Trello's problem.